# cv::dnn::readNetFromDarknet() error in reading configutaion files on heroku

Tags: opencv, flask, heroku

Hello I am deploying an object detection flask API on heroku but I have been running into this error for a week :

> cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(config_path, weights_path)
> 2021-12-04T17:22:47.972153+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4)
> /tmp/pip-req-build-24v3eisa/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:933: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Transpose the
> weights (except for convolutional) is not implemented in function
> 'ReadDarknetFromWeightsStream'

any help will be welcome
here is the function used to load the yolo model:

```
def load_yolov4_model():
# derive a path of yolo weight 
outFileFolder = 'yolo-coco/'
weights_path = outFileFolder +"yolov4-custom_parts.weights"
config_path = outFileFolder + "yolov4-custom1.cfg"
print("[INFO] loading yolo from disk...")
yolov4_model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(config_path, 
 weights_path)

return yolov4_model
```

Comment: Are you really using a darknet model? Trained with the darknet framework from pjreddie or alexeyAB? Or are you using a third party framework? Did you try loading one if the pretrained official networks like yolo v2, yolo v3 or yolo v4 (not v5)?

Comment: yes I used darkent from AlexAB then I trained on my own dataset. When I read the model from my laptop it works but it's on heroku that I have this problem

Comment: can you try loading the original pretrained network without training with your own data? However, if it's working on your local machine with same opencv source code that might be not the problem. Which opencv versions do you use in both cases?

Comment: yes it works if I use the same code with the pretained yolov4 weights and I use opencv 4.5.3 in both cases
I think the problem may be in how heroku store  larges files like .weights

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.